# Client Certificate Common Name: Mutual SSL

Tags: tls

I'm currently working on a project where I'm trying to send data to a 3rd party service that utilizes two-way SSL.

My current setup includes a few servers that will each send data to the service. Each server has a unique address and no associated hostname.

Since I have multiple servers with different addresses, will I need to create a CSR for each server with the common name being the address of the server?

If not, what will I need to put as the common name for the CSR?

Comment: If the server does not have a hostname, what is the certificate for?

Comment: Its for the 3rd party client to verify the incoming the incoming sender as apart of the two way handshake. Do you know if i need a hostname associated on my servers?

Comment: You should ask 3rd party (you are connecting to) and clarify how do they suppose to authenticate you and what names they expect.

Comment: You have multiple questions here - please focus on one. As for the name in the client certificate: this is a duplicate. As for having different CSR: given that you want to authenticate and identify a client you need to have a different certificate for each client.